# Onclick function does not work in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a button that is supposed to have `onclick="submitItem()"` but the function does not work when it is created in an external javascript file (`app.js`).

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="submitItem()">Save</button>
```

When the function is placed in between script tags, then it works, but that's not what I want.

```
  <script src="./js/app.js" type="module"></script>
  <script>
    function submitItem() {
      alert("works");
    }
  </script>
```

But this does not work:

```
app.js

function submitItem() {
  alert("does not work");
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @mrddr — It'll be a reference error because `submitItem` isn't defined anywhere that is is scope for the onclick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a module. Don't claim it is. Remove `type="module"`.

(Top-level variables, including those created by function declarations, are scoped to the module and not as globals in ES6 module scripts).